# Is it possible to define the ** operator in F#

Tags: f#, custom-operator

```
let (**) ls1 ls2 = List.intersect ls1 ls2
```

does not work because (**) is considered a comment. Is there any escape possibility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add whitespace inside the parentheses, like this:

```
let ( ** ) ls1 ls2 = List.intersect ls1 ls2
```

Keep in mind, however, that `**` is a standard F# operator for "power":

```
2 ** 3 = 8
```

So if you redefine it like this in the global context, you will not be able to use it in the "power" sense.